# 500 internal_failure with Google Signin when using Google Apps account

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

My web page with the Google Signin javascript SDK works great with normal Google accounts. When I try Google Apps accounts, I get an error on the console:

GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?yaddayadda... 500 (Internal Server Error)

Hitting this URL gives me:

```
{
    error: "internal_failure"
}
```

Is there some way to make the Google Signin Javascript SDK work with Google Apps accounts?